# Sugestão de usuário nos comentários não funciona em dispositivo móvel

Tags: bug, comentários

Fui tentar enviar um comentário hoje pelo celular e notei que ao digitar o `@` e a primeira letra do nome do usuário, o site não sugere os nomes dos usuários que estão participando dos comentários, como acontece na versão desktop do site.

Sistema:
Android 8.1.0, versão do kernel 3.18.71-perf-gd0e0d1a

Navegador:
Google Chrome 70.0.3538.80

Comment: Acredito que o app não tenha suporte para isso mesmo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Acho que ele está falando de acessar o site no browser do celular. E de fato, qdo acesso no Chrome do celular, acontece isso mesmo, não sugere os nomes quando digito `@`.

Comment: Isso, pelo browser mesmo, eu não uso o app, eu instalei há um tempo atrás mas só conseguia ver o SOen por lá e acabei deixando de lado. É possível acessar o SOpt pelo app também? O acesso pelo app é mais rico do que o acesso pelo navegador móvel?

Comment: Isto é na versão mobile do site, e não na versão desktop com "responsiveness" activada, certo?

Comment: Isso, eu estava acessando pelo celular, usando o Chrome, quando notei o problema.